# Migration From Tokumx 1.5 To Percona Server For mongodb 3.11

Tags: mongodb, server, database-migration, percona, tokumx

Migrating Data from Tokumx To Percona Server For MonoDB

Step 1 :
This guide describes how to upgrade existing Percona TokuMX instance to Percona Server for MongoDB. The following JavaScript files are required to perform the upgrade:

```
• allDbStats.js
• tokumx_dump_indexes.js
• psmdb_restore_indexes.js
```

You can download those files from GitHub.

Step 2 :
Run the allDbStats.js script to record database state before migration:
     $ mongo   ./allDbStats.js   >    ~/allDbStats.before.out

Step 3 :
Perform a dump of the database:
     $ mongodump --out /your/dump/path

Step 4 :
Perform a dump of the indexes:
    $ ./tokumx_dump_indexes.js     >     /your/dump/path/tokumxIndexes.json

Step 5 :
Restore the collections without indexes using “--noIndexRestore” switch:
    $ mongorestore   --noIndexRestore   /your/dump/path

Step 6 :
Restore the indexes (this may take a while). This step will remove clustering options to the collections before inserting.

$./psmdb_restore_indexes.js --eval "data='/your/dump/path/tokumxIndexes.json' "

Step 7 :

Run the allDbStats.js script to record database state after migration:

```
mongo ./allDbStats.js   >   ~/allDbStats.after.out
```

This is the guide i have found in the Migration from Tokumx to Percona server for mongodb. at step 6 when i try to restore indexes i get below mentioned error :

```
 /mnt/tokumx-bkup/tokumxIndexes.json
 2016-06-29T05:28:20.028+0000 E QUERY    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

  at /tmp/tokumx2_to_psmdb3_migration-master/psmdb_restore_indexes.js:78:1 at               /mnt/tokumx-bkup/tokumxIndexes.json

 2016-06-29T05:28:20.028+0000 E QUERY    Error: error loading js file:    /mnt/tokumx-bkup/tokumxIndexes.json

  at /tmp/tokumx2_to_psmdb3_migration-master/psmdb_restore_indexes.js:78:1 at    /tmp/tokumx2_to_psmdb3_migration-master/psmdb_restore_indexes.js:78
```

failed to load: /tmp/tokumx2_to_psmdb3_migration-master/psmdb_restore_indexes.js

Any help will be welcomed.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the tokumxIndexes.json file.   When tokumx_dump_indexes.js is run,  the mongo shell parameter --quiet must be used or the resulting json will contain the shell preamble at the beginning.

And check the file using something like http://jsonlint.com/

Also if preamble is present delete these two lines from the tokumxIndexes.json file.
"MongoDB shell version: 3.0.11-1.6
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27017/test"

and Run the script again.
and Run the script again
$./psmdb_restore_indexes.js --eval "data='/your/dump/path/tokumxIndexes.json' "
Now this script will start build Index Process.

Comment: I am the script author,  and I approve of this answer :)