# Data Migration From Tokumx 1.5 To Percona MongoDB Server 3

Tags: mongodb, data-migration, percona, tokumx, database

I want to migrate from TokuMX 1.5 to Percona MongoDB server 3.11. Following Data Migration guide provided by [percona](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server-for-mongodb/3.2/install/upgrade_from_tokumx.htmlion) .
which works fine, but at:

> Step 12 : Restore the indexes (this may take a while). This step will
>   remove clustering options to the collections before inserting.
>
> $./psmdb_restore_indexes.js --eval "
>   data='/your/dump/path/tokumxIndexes.json' "

My migration fails and gives the following error:

```
/mnt/tokumx-bkup/tokumxIndexes.json
 2016-06-29T05:28:20.028+0000 E QUERY    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
  at /tmp/tokumx2_to_psmdb3_migration-master/psmdb_restore_indexes.js:78:1 at /mnt/tokumx-bkup/tokumxIndexes.json
 2016-06-29T05:28:20.028+0000 E QUERY    Error: error loading js file:  /mnt/tokumx-bkup/tokumxIndexes.json
  at /tmp/tokumx2_to_psmdb3_migration-master/psmdb_restore_indexes.js:78:1 at  /tmp/tokumx2_to_psmdb3_migration-master/psmdb_restore_indexes.js:78
  failed to load: /tmp/tokumx2_to_psmdb3_migration-master/psmdb_restore_indexes.js
```

Can someone please help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: Please describe in more detail what you did, what you want to achieve and where exactly you have problems.

Comment: Question Posted With More Detail at following Link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38091106/migration-from-tokumx-1-5-to-percona-server-for-mongodb-3-11

Comment: I am the script author:

Can you check the /your/dump/path/tokumxIndexes.json data file?   It must be generated using the mongo shell --quiet option or the shell preamble will output to the file.